# Xcode9 codesign error when using ARKit

Tags: compiler-errors, ios11, codesign, arkit, xcode9-beta

I am working on an ARKit app in Xcode9 (the last beta before the GM). I've imported the mesh model, and then attached a png image as my material. When compiling, it gives me this error, "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1." If I take off the image and just make the whole mesh a color, it compiles fine and the app augments the model perfectly. Has anyone else come across this while using ARKit?

Answer (score 0):

I would check your build log and see exactly what the codesign command being emitted by Xcode is, then try running it on the command line after the build fails with the additional `-v` flag so you get more information than -1. As a guess, I'd say your app may be missing an entitlement for handling the image. Perhaps it is accessing the camera roll?